# SQL Join query error in JSF 2.2 with Oracle 11g XE database

Tags: java, sql, oracle, join, jdbc

Hi everybody I am coding a Library Management System with using JSF 2.2 and Oracle XE 11g database. I have seperate tables like Borrowers Books etc. and certainly some web pages like Borrowers.xhtml and Books.xhtml. In my Borrowers table thee is a foreign key named Bookid. It references to Book table's primary key named Id. They both are Number(5) type attributes. I want to show book names which people borrowed. Now I can only show bookid s. I writed a join sql but this did not work. I have the following in book names line [DataPackage.Book[ isbn=null ]] My codes:

```
public List<Book> getBookNames(int bookid2)throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException{
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","Alparslan-PC","123456");

    BookidPs = con.prepareStatement("SELECT DISTINCT TITLE FROM BOOK JOIN BORROWER ON BOOK.ISBN= "+bookid2);
    ResultSet Rs2 = BookidPs.executeQuery();
    List<Book> liste = new ArrayList<Book>();
    while(Rs2.next()){
        book.setTitle(Rs2.getString("TITLE"));
        liste.add(book);
    }
    System.out.print(liste);
    return liste;
}
```

I tried to turn list to string. (deleted list and wrote String instead of it) I tried everything but this code gives me that error I have written on the top. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ON clause doesn't actually make the join on the referenced column. Try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.Title FROM BOOK b
JOIN Borrower bo ON b.id = bo.BookID
WHERE b.ISBN = ?
```

Comment: thanks for answer but it is Borrower. No mistake there.

Comment: [DataPackage.Book[ isbn=null ]] again. it runs on Oracle and gives the right solution but. Do not work on JSF.

Comment: If ISBN is null and you want to match on that you have to use `IS NULL` instead of `=`.

Comment: What do you mean you have to use IS NULL instead of = I deleted = and writed IS NULL instead of = is this what you mean

Comment: The tests `x = NULL` and `x != NULL` will always return false, if you want to check if x is or is not null you have to use `x IS NULL` or `x IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query

```
"SELECT DISTINCT book.Title FROM BOOK 
JOIN Borrower ON   book.isbn= Borrower.BookID
WHERE Nvl (book.isbn,"+bookid2+")="+bookid2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am getting same error when I write like this. In this StackOverflow ocean is not anyone who know this. what is Nvl ?

Comment: i have edited nvl is used to return bookid2 if book.isbn has null value

Comment: I have already done just like this. but result is the same. nothing changed. I do not understand. I have books I have borrowers but I could not show just their names. interesting.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the correct way to do it. Thanks to @psaraj12 Here is the code:

```
public String getBookNames(int bookid2)throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException{
    Book book2 = new Book();
    book2.setIsbn(bookid2);
    String str = null;
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","Alparslan-PC","123456");
    BookidPs = con.prepareStatement("SELECT DISTINCT BOOK.TITLE FROM BOOK " +
            "JOIN BORROWER ON BOOK.ISBN= BORROWER.BOOKID " +
            "WHERE Nvl (BOOK.ISBN,"+bookid2+")="+bookid2);
    ResultSet Rs2 = BookidPs.executeQuery();
    while(Rs2.next()){
        str = Rs2.getString("TITLE");
    }
    System.out.print(str);
    return str;
}
```

When I tried this I can show my book names.